# Why is argc given as a parameter to main when we do not actually pass it?

Tags: c

Why is `argc` is given as a parameter in C (i.e. `int main(int argc, char **argv)`) when we actually do not pass the count of our arguments?

I want to know why the syntax is written in such a way when `argc` does not take the parameter passed.  Why didn't they design it as a keyword or a function like `length` when it is written only for us to know the count?

Comment: `argc` is the number of elements in the `argv` array. I don't understand what you mean when you say "we actual [sic] do not pass the count of our arguments"? What is the actual problem you have? Why do you ask this question?

Comment: `argc` can also equal 0. That's still a piece of info the program could use.

Comment: I think you mean `char *argv[]`?

Comment: Why it is passed as an argument? Well, this is a design decision. It could have been placed somewhere else and compiled in as a keyword or function, as you suggest, but why? Taking it as a parameter to main seems to me like the best, easiest and safest way.

Comment: They also could make all the keywords spelled backwards, but didn't. Why? Probably because there's no reason to.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that when one of the `exec*()` family of functions is called, you do not specify the number of arguments explicitly — that is indicated by the presence of a null pointer at the end of a list of arguments.

The count is passed to the `int main(int argc, char **argv)` function for convenience, so that the code does not have to step through the entire argument list to determine how many arguments are present.  It is only convenience — since `argv[argc] == 0` is guaranteed, you can determine the end of the arguments unambiguously.

For the rest, the reason is historical — it was done that way from the start, and there has been no reason to change it (and every reason not to change it).

It isn't clear what you mean by 'a keyword' for the argument count.  C has very few keywords, and one for this purpose would be peculiar.  Similarly, although there could be a function to do the job, that isn't really necessary — the interface chosen obviates the need for such a function.  It might have been useful to have functional access to the argument list (and the environment) so that library code could enumerate the arguments and environment.  (Using `getenv()`, you can find out about environment variables you know about; you can't find out about environment variables which you don't know about.  On POSIX systems, there is the `extern char **environ;` variable that be used to enumerate the content of the environment, but that's not part of Standard C.)